# Creating a voting system in Django rest framework by saving usernames on each vote

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF and I want to build my own voting system using likes, dislikes and neutral. I have the front end set up so when the user likes an image I want to his user id to be saved within the post model, and so on for the dislikes.

```
class Posts(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name =      'user_posts')
   image = models.ImageField('optionalImage', upload_to='images/posts/', default='/images/posts/blank.png')
   likes = models.TextField(max_length=200, default=0)
   dislikes = models.TextField(max_length=200, default=0)
   neutral = models.TextField(max_length=200, default=0)
```

I have the following questions:

1) How do I save a list of usernames like [14,33,22...] since I can't use a text field for the same.

2) Is it a good structure to maintain the likes and dislikes within the same post and update them on every put request by saving the userid of the user within the respective choice made(likes, dislikes) or should they be a separated into a different model?

3) What is the best way to check if the user has seen a particular post before using this model? Would I have to check through the likes, dislike and neutral list to see if the user has acted on the post? Or would I require another unique identifier? I need to do this in order to return new posts to the user.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4):

How about a vote model?

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    upvote = models.BooleanField()
```

In my opinion you should not store the likes and dislikes directly in your post model.

**Edit:**

or maybe something like this:

```
class Like(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
   post = models.ForeignKey(Post)

class Dislike(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
   post = models.ForeignKey(Post)

class Read(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
   post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
```

or this:

```
class PostAction(models.Model):
   POST_ACTION_TYPES = ((LIKE, 'Like'), (DISLIKE, 'Dislike'), (READ, 'Read'))
   action_type = models.CharField(choices=POST_ACTION_TYPES) 
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
   post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
```

Comment: does this answer your question?

Comment: I would use ManyToMany fields instead of ForeignKey, that way you have control of what happens to the votes if a User or Post is deleted